# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, spark-streaming

It look like the class StreamingContext is not found in the following code.

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
object Exemple {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Exemple")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2)) //this line throws error

  }
}
```

here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext
    at Exemple$.main(Exemple.scala:16)
    at Exemple.main(Exemple.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I use the following build.sbt file:

```
name := "exemple"

version := "1.0.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.2.0"
```

I run the Exemple class using intellij Run button and I get the error. in sbt shell it work fine. into my dependecies'module, I can find spark dependencies. The code compile in intellij. And I can see in the External Libraries spark dependies (inside the left project panel).
Do you have any idea. It seem not complicated.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please remove `provided` term from spark-streaming library.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.2.0"
```

After the changes, still having dependency issues further, exclude the duplicate jars.

```
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.2.0" excludeAll(
      ExclusionRule(organization = "org.spark-project.spark", name = "unused"),
      ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.spark", name = "spark-streaming"),
      ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.hadoop")
    ),
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: Thank You very much. Remove provided do the job